# In a 'self-stabilized' distributed system, where a fault occurs?

Tags: distributed-systems

Consider a *self-stabilized* distributed system based on *shared memory* and the processor $p_{i}$ be connected to the processor $p_{j}$. Suppose we are going to solve a problem like *finding a maximal independent set* or *minimal dominating set* and we need to break symmetry. For breaking symmetry, we use id of processors.

**My Question:** When $p_{i}$ reads the id of $p_{j}$, a failure can occurs in this operation?

Comment: I don't think the question is answerable with the information available.  it depends on the model of computation, and what kinds of failures that model allows.